# My Mac is very slow and lagged while connecting with ViewSonic screen

Tags: display, catalina, screen, hdmi

My Mac started to behave unusually when I connected it with the ViewSonic TD2420 monitor. For example, it would take too much time to open a folder. However, when I went to "About This Mac", then it lists the TD2420 display and allows me to make some changes.

My questions:

- What's the issue?
- Is this screen non-compatible with macOS?
- How do I maintain good performance while my Mac is connected to the monitor?

I'm running macOS Catalina.

Comment: Which Mac do you have?

Comment: Did you use a Thunderbolt 3 cable to connect the monitor?

Comment: Viewsonic's page on this screen only lists compatibility with Win 7 & 8. https://www.viewsonic.com/uk/products/archive/TD2420.php

Comment: According to https://www.viewsonic.com/my/products/lcd/TD2420.php?prv=1, there's compatibility with Mac, but no touch support

Comment: @Ahmed which country are you in?  There seems to be a difference in specifications between the UK and the US spec versions of this model.  The US model is compatible with Macs, with the exceptions of the touch support, while the UK model does not seem to be compatible with Macs at all. Also, it would be very helpful to know which Mac you have, and what port you are using to plug in the monitor

Comment: My MAC is MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014) - THE OS is the latest one Catalina

Comment: You never mentioned how you're connecting - I would go with a mini DisplayPort to DVI.  don't go VGA or HDMI.  VGA is old and HDMI is problematic in computing environments.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of factors that may limit you from running the monitor at optimal performance:

```
Graphics card drivers 
Video cable adapters 
Docking stations
```

These are discussed in more detail at [this site](https://support.viewsonic.com/en/support/solutions/articles/33000251341-where-can-i-get-macos-drivers-for-my-display-) and it gives some instructions to get optimal performance from your Viewsonic monitor connected to a mac.

Also [this site](https://www.viewsonic.com/hk/asset-files/files/datasheets/lcd/24/e-td2420.pdf) claims your monitor is compatible with Macs but the touch function doesn't work. See the image below of the last page of the link.

[image]

Comment: BTY , I posted the issue in Apple discussions : https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251569036

Comment: The post here : https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/395910/why-kernal-task-kill-the-process

Answer (score 0):

When I researched on the internet, it appeared that the monitor is not fully compatible with macOS/OS X. It also notes [here](https://www.viewsonic.com/uk/products/archive/TD2420.php) that it is only supported in Windows 7 and 8 PCs.